# How to install ODP.net in VS 2010?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

Hello guys I have VS 2010 and I am following this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/building_odt.htm#TDPNG50010) but I don't have the Oracle Data Provider for .NET see this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGy7A.jpg). What to do?. Please teach.

Answer (score 0):

Download Oracle Data Provider from [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html) and install it. Then it should work.

In case you have it installed already, open your Registry editor and check if RegKey `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.NET` resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.NET` exist. Both RegKeys contain only the `(Default)` value with location of your `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`.

Example:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.Net]
    @="c:\\oracle\\product\\11.2\\Client_x86\\odp.net\\bin\\2.x"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\ODP.Net]
    @="c:\\oracle\\product\\11.2\\Client_x86\\odp.net\\bin\\4"
```

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257694/ins-50013-error-when-installing-oui) I got the same problem as his.